tmap centralize tm_fill title above legend
I  need to center the title above the legend. I've tried many combinations of title X legend parameters of tm_layout, to no avail.
I am using tmap 3.3.4.
My last code:
ce_map <- tm_shape(shp_setor) +
  tm_fill(
    "v0001"
    , palette = "viridis"
    , title = "População do Ceará" 
    , legend.is.portrait = F
    , breaks = quebras
    , labels = labels 
  ) +
  tm_layout(
    legend.position = c("center","bottom")
    , legend.stack = "horizontal"
    , title.position = c("center","bottom")
    , legend.just = "center"
    , legend.width = 1
    , legend.title.size = 1.6
    , inner.margins = c(.14, .02, .02, .02)
    , bg.color = cor
    , frame = F
  )


Do you have any idea?
